# Get old value in transaction test window

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I Create a asset called record having the record data as a String. During the transaction , 
we want to see the record data value in playground during transaction window and modify the value.
I can see one example where they change the value from oldvalue to new value.

But, my condition I want to see the data first during the submit transaction in playground test and change it. Could you please suggest
Also, same question , if i want get the state which is defined via enum. Please suggest

```
asset Record identified by recordId {
  o String recordId
  o String data
}

transaction UpdateRecord{
--> Record asset
  o String newData

}

/**
 * Update Record
 * @param {org.acme.model.UpdateRecord} updateRecord - the updateRecord transaction
 * @transaction
 */
function UpdateRecord(record) {
    record.asset.data = record.newData;
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.model.Record')
      .then(function (assetRegistry) {
          return assetRegistry.update(record.asset);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The world state DB is at any one time, an up-to-date view on the current state of the ledger - a snapshot if you like. It gets updated once the transaction has been endorsed then committed (it won't be in that state immediately after the update call in your transaction processor - so if you retrieve a value (in your function code, thereafter) from the world state it will still have the 'old' state - of course. Any exceptions thrown from a transaction processor function will cause the entire transaction to be rolled back, leaving no changes to the blockchain or world state.

So if you execute one transaction (add record) through playground, you should get the transaction id back for the create. eg, add asset. Then when you update that asset using a transaction (thru playground, through APIs, through REST) to execute your txn processor, then once that has completed you will get another transaction id - and the function will update the original asset according to your code. To see the 'record data' - an asset in your definition, just use 'Test' tab having first connected to your BN in playground and you can see the 'Historian record'(which is still being developed at the time of writing pls note) to see the history of transactions you carried out. To see the detail of that transaction presently, use the REST APIS (created for your business network using composer-rest-server) or system transaction id via REST to see the individual transaction, as mentioned on RC